# ¿Cómo puedo crear un nuevo usuario en mariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Intenté crear un nuevo usario en MariaDB siguiendo [este documentacion](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/administration-guide/databases/mysql.html#connecting-to-mysql-8-servers) pero parece que me falta cosas al escribir el password:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'metabase'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password_es_veramente_lo_queescribi 
       BY 'thepassword';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY 'thepassword'' at line 1
```

Sin embargo me pareció que el comando dado había hecho algo no muy malo [según la sintaxis](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/):

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] USER [IF NOT EXISTS] 
 user_specification [,user_specification ...] 
  [REQUIRE {NONE | tls_option [[AND] tls_option ...] }]
  [WITH resource_option [resource_option ...] ]
  [lock_option] [password_option] 

user_specification:
  username [authentication_option]

authentication_option:
  IDENTIFIED BY 'password' 
  | IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password_hash'
  | IDENTIFIED {VIA|WITH} authentication_rule [OR authentication_rule  ...]

authentication_rule:
    authentication_plugin
  | authentication_plugin {USING|AS} 'authentication_string'
  | authentication_plugin {USING|AS} PASSWORD('password')

tls_option:
  SSL 
  | X509
  | CIPHER 'cipher'
  | ISSUER 'issuer'
  | SUBJECT 'subject'

resource_option:
  MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR count
  | MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR count
  | MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR count
  | MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS count
  | MAX_STATEMENT_TIME time

password_option:
  PASSWORD EXPIRE
  | PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT
  | PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER
  | PASSWORD EXPIRE INTERVAL N DAY

lock_option:
    ACCOUNT LOCK
  | ACCOUNT UNLOCK
}
```

Intenté la solucion de Javier G.Raya:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'RevolucionForMonica'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Y no tengo los derechos para accederle como root

```
PS C:\Users\antoi> mysql -uroot -pelpassworddeRevolucionForMonicaqueesadministrador
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Intenté cambiar el password del usuario que intenta crear este nuevo usario `metabase`:

```
PS C:\Users\antoi> mysqladmin -u revolucionformonica password password
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Comment: Si, @JavierG.Raya , no es literalmente `RevolucionForMonica` pero el que utiliso para connectarme a la base de datos

Comment: en SO ingles esta resuelto : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw

Comment: ¡Bien! ¿Qué respuestas? ¿Y por qué usas mysqladmin en lugar de mysql, @JavierG.Raya ?

Comment: es como lo tengo en mis apuntes

Comment: Estoy conectado a mi instancia de Amazon EC2. Puedo iniciar sesión con el administrado de MySQL RevolucionforMonica @JavierG.Raya

Comment: presupongo que la respuesta con el check en verde es la que le funciono en SO ingles : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11216911/12464880

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135941/discussion-between-javier-g-raya-and-revolucion-for-monica).

Answer (score 0):

***1.*** Accede a la línea de comando de ***MariaDB***  con el siguiente comando :

```
mysql -u root -p
```

***2.*** Crear el **usuarios con la contraseña**.

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

En este ejemplo creo el usuario user con la contraseña password.

***3.*** **Dar permisos al usuario user**.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

***4.*** Aplicas los cambios y te sale del terminal.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EXIT;
```

***5.*** Accede con el usuario nueva al terminal de ***MariaDB***.

```
mysql -u user -p
```

***6.*** Comprobar que los privilegios se ha creado correctamente :

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user';
```

**En caso de que no funcione hacer primero esto :**

Esto se debe a que por defecto el password de revolucionforNomica para la base de datos no está fijado, así que lo vamos a crear nosotros con un comando.

```
mysqladmin -u user password [newpassword]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias para la respuesta pero en `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'superuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
 no es `'user'` en este caso?

Comment: si es usar gracias que no me di cuenta, lo cogí de mi plantilla de MySQL que básicamente es lo mismo que MariaDB

Comment: No hay problema, pero tengo un problema con este commando hasta que me parece que el usario que uso, que da 'ALL PRIVILEGES' no hay permisos de darlos.

Comment: Lamentablemente no tengo acceso a root

Comment: Hmm, pero ya tengo una contraseña para revolucionformonica, es `elpassworddeRevolucionForMonicaqueesadministrador`